# Typeahead doesn't read attribute created after initial page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using bootstrap-typeahead.js v2.0.3 and JQuery v1.7.2.

I have a form, loaded from a Bootstrap modal, with two text boxes that need to use typeahead.

```html
<input id="filter___hotspot_id" class="filter_typeahead required_filter" data-filter-context="name" data-filter-tablename="hotspots" data-filter-columnname="name" style="width: 200px" autocomplete="off" type="text">
<input id="filter__interface" class="filter_typeahead required_filter" data-filter-context="default" data-filter-tablename="hotspot_interfaces" data-filter-columnname="name" data-filter-additional-col="hotspot_id" data-filter-additional-id="11" style="width: 200px" autocomplete="off" type="text">
```

Depending on the data entered on the first text box, two attributes are added to the second box (the data-filter-additional-col and data-filter-additional-id attributes in the filter__interface item above). That gets done OK, using this piece of code:

```
$( document ).on( 'change', '#filter___hotspot_id', function () {
    var interface_filter = $('#filter__interface');
    var id_parts = $( this ).val().split( ' id:' );
    interface_filter.attr('data-filter-additional-col', 'hotspot_id' );
    interface_filter.attr('data-filter-additional-id', id_parts[id_parts.length - 1] );
    // This is the call to a function to reload the code where the ajax call is below in this question:
    FUNC.typeahead.init();
});
```

The ajax function that calls the typeahead is loaded when the page is initially loaded:

```
    $( p_field_obj )
        .typeahead({
            ajax: {
                url: 'ajax_handler.php?command=ajax-typeahead&tablename=' + 
                        $( p_field_obj ).attr( 'data-filter-tablename' ) + 
                        '&columnname=' + $( p_field_obj ).attr( 'data-filter-columnname' ) + 
                        '&context=' + $( p_field_obj ).attr( 'data-filter-context' ) +
                        '&additional_col=' + $(p_field_obj).attr('data-filter-additional-col') +
                        '&additional_id=' + $(p_field_obj).attr('data-filter-additional-id'),
                timeout: 300,
                triggerLength: 2,
                loadingClass: 'search_in_progress',
                preProcess: function( data ) {
                    retval = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
                    return retval;
                } 
            },
            matcher: function( item ) { return item; },  // Stops the client filtering the results coming back from AJAX.
            items: 999  // We rely on the AJAX server handler to return the right number of matches (ie LIMIT on the SQL query).
        });
```

The problem is that when the typeahead function is called from the second text box, the context where the typeahead is doesn't see the added attributes. How can I make the value of the added attributes available when the typeahead function is called?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is `p_field_obj` ?

Comment: It's the object for each of the filter_typeahead items, i.e: **p_field_obj = $('#filter___hotspot_id')**

Comment: What are _"the added attributes"_ ?

Comment: data-filter-additional-id and data-filter-additional-col, which get added onto filter__interface depending on the data entered into filter___hotspot_id.

Comment: Where within `js` at Question are `data-filter-additional-id` , `data-filter-additional-col` "added" as attributes to `filter__interface` ?

Comment: Yes, those two attributes are added by js to filter__interface after some data is entered into filter__hotspot_id. I've got some their values logged onto the console, which shows they're OK. It's just the ajax call which doesn't seem to be aware of them (they come as undefined).

Comment: See `p_field_obj = $('#filter___hotspot_id')` ?  Where is `filter__interface` defined ?

Comment: Just edited question adding piece of code where the attributes are added.

Comment: p_field_obj is defined by some magic behind the scenes (part of bootstrap-typeahead.js v2.0.3, which I don't really know the details of). Basically each item with class=''filter_typeahead" will be defined as p_field_obj.

Comment: What is `FUNC.typeahead.init();` ? The `change` event appear to occur independently of `.typeahead()` ? can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=ud9FSE4fE7

Comment: Check jsfiddle link ?

Comment: guest271314, thanks very much for trying to help. There were quite a few separate bits of code involved in this problem, which made it difficult to try and put some snippets to explain it. I've been doing some research and have found no way to get the data changed in the bootstrap modal refreshed and available to the typeahead function. I've given up and tried another alternative, which seems to work. Thanks again. This is the first time I post a question and don't really know the procedure to close it. If anyone else can, please feel free to close it.

Comment: You are welcome:) See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284405/